# Openssl x509v3 Extended Key Usage

Tags: openssl, x509certificate

I know you can specify the purpose for which a certificate public key can be used for by adding a line like this one in the *openssl.cfg* file:

```
extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth,clientAuth
```

But since I have several certificates to create, each with a different extended key usage, is it possible to specify which attribute I need in the command line (without using the openssl.cfg file)? Something like:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 \
            -extendedKeyUsage "serverAuth,clientAuth" \
            -keyform PEM \
            -keyout server-key.pem \
            -out server-req.csr \
            -outform PEM
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 40):

You can only use something like this:

```
openssl -extensions mysection -config myconfig.cnf
```

and myconfig.cnf:

```
[mysection]
keyUsage         = digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage = codeSigning
```

I am not aware of command line interface to this functionality.

Comment: I get this: `unable to find 'distinguished_name' in config`

Comment: @MarinosAn, given config contains only parts relevant to the question. You may have to provide few more extra parameters. This is out of the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 24):

You may try addext:

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt \
    -subj '/CN=User1' \
    -addext extendedKeyUsage=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.80.1 \
    -addext keyUsage=keyEncipherment
```

Works on openssl 1.1.1a

Comment: What is the sequence `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.80.1` stands for? should be replaced with `extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth, clientAuth, codeSigning, emailProtection`?

Comment: this is Microsoft specific extension (PKI) (I guess there is no corresponding name in openssl) This is more like an example that you can use OID rather than using names (which you might not known)

Comment: @cactuschibre it won't work on older versions. Which one you are using?

Answer (score 14):

What I ended up doing is creating several different openssl.cfg files and refer to the proper one by using either the **-config** or the **-extfile** switch.

Comment: you might want to "accept" your own answer (so it won't show up as unanswered question anymore)

Answer (score 6):

the same as processing SAN

`openssl req -subj "/CN=client" -sha256 -new -key client-key.pem -out client.csr\
    -reqexts SAN -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf "\n[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.com\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth,clientAuth"))`

Answer (score 4):

With recent version of OpenSSL you can use [`-addext`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-req.html#addext-ext) option to add **extended key usage**.

For you specific case this should looks like :

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 \                          
            -addext "extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth, clientAuth" \
            -keyform PEM \
            -keyout server-key.pem \
            -out server-req.csr \
            -outform PEM
```

You can verify the output with :

```
openssl req -noout -text  -in server-req.csr
```

A more common use case is to also set **subject** and **key usage**.

With same example :

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 \
            -subj '/CN=My Name' \
            -addext "keyUsage = digitalSignature,keyAgreement" \
            -addext "extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth, clientAuth" \
            -keyform PEM \
            -keyout server-key.pem \
            -out server-req.csr \
            -outform PEM
```

Answer (score 3):

Mike Twc, https://stackoverflow.com/users/7775187/mike-twc absolutely right! Unfortunately, there is not enough reputation to mark his answer as correct and add an extension to his answer, so I write a new answer ...
You need to use -addext, but keep in mind that the `key->value` parameter is here, and all values must be separated by commas.

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout efs.key -out efs.crt -days 36500 -subj '/CN=EFS/O=Company' -addext 'extendedKeyUsage=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4.1'
```

Comment: you can add a comment to that answer instead of a separate answer

Comment: @dtech due to rating limits, I couldn't do it before