# Client server authentication with self signed certificate - Curl is working but Apache HttpClient throws exception

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, self-signed-certificate

I'm trying to implement client and server authentication with Apache HTTPClient,
and to test it with a self signed certificate.
I've tried to follow several tutorials and answers to similar questions here but
with no success. I've tried to detail as much as possible all the steps that I've
been doing, hopefully someone can point out what I'm doing wrong:

1. Created a file `req.conf` for configuration

   ```
   [req]
   prompt=no
   distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name

   [ req_distinguished_name ]
   O=selfSignedO
   CN=selfSignedCn
   DC=selfSignedDc
   ```
2. Generated server private key and the self-signed certificate

   ```
   openssl req \
    -config req.conf \
    -x509 \
    -newkey rsa:4096 \
    -keyout server/server-private-key.pem \
    -out server/server.crt \
    -days 3650 \
    -nodes
   ```
3. Created PKCS12 keystore containing the private key and certificate created in the previous step

   ```sh
    openssl pkcs12 \
    -export \
    -out server/server-key-store.p12 \
    -inkey server/server-private-key.pem \
    -in server/server.crt
   ```

   let's say the password I used was `123456`
4. Generated a client private key and a certificate signing request

   ```sh
   openssl req \
    -config req.conf \
    -new \
    -newkey rsa:4096 \
    -out client/client-request.csr \
    -keyout client/client-private-key.pem \
    -nodes
   ```
5. Signed the client's certificate signing request with the server's private key 
   and certificate

   ```sh
   openssl x509 \
    -req \
    -days 360 \
    -in client/client-request.csr \
    -CA server/server.crt \
    -CAkey server/server-private-key.pem \
    -CAcreateserial \
    -out client/client-signed-cert.crt \
    -sha256
   ```
6. Created a PKCS12 keystore containing the client's private key and certificate certificate created in the previous step.

   ```sh
    openssl pkcs12 \
     -export \
     -out client/client-keystore.p12 \
     -inkey client/client-private-key.pem \
     -in client/client-signed-cert.crt \
     -certfile server/server.crt
   ```

   we used `123456` as password again.
7. Generated server trust store containing the client signed certificate

   ```sh
   keytool \
    -import \
    -trustcacerts \
    -alias root \
    -file client/client-signed-cert.crt \
    -keystore server/server-trust-store.jks
   ```

   password? `123456`
8. Curl is working, but only with `-k`

   ```sh
   curl -k \
      --cert client/client-signed-cert.crt \
      --key client/client-private-key.pem \
      https://localhost:443:/my/endpoint
   ```

   without the `-k` I get the error:

   ```sh
   curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
   More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

   curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
    of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
    bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
    using the --cacert option.
   If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
    the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
    problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
    not match the domain name in the URL).
   If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
    the -k (or --insecure) option.
   HTTPS-proxy has similar options --proxy-cacert and --proxy-insecure.
   ```
9. Configured Apache HTTPClient:

   ```java
   private HttpClient createClient() throws Exception {
       String keyPassword = "123456";
       KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
       ks.load(resourceAsStream("/client/client-key-store.p12"), keyPassword.toCharArray());
       SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
           .setProtocol("TLSv1.2")
           .loadKeyMaterial(ks, keyPassword.toCharArray())
           .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
           .build()
       return HttpClients.custom()
               .setSSLContext(sslContext)
               .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
               .build();
   }
   ```

   (The construction is done via multiple methods that I squeezed here to one, so if something is weird or missing please let me know, perhaps I miscopy-pasted something.)

but when trying to send the same request as with Curl I'm getting:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2038)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1135)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1779)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Handshaker.java:1156)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(ClientHandshaker.java:1266)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1178)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:348)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
```

Comment: You might have to check key-usage of your cert.

Comment: @beat - can you please elaborate?

Comment: When creating with OpenSSL you might need to set the clientAuth keyusage, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089889/openssl-x509v3-extended-key-usage

Comment: Also: try to enable debugging with -Djavax.net.debug=all, which might give you some hints

Comment: tried adding the `keyUsage` and `extendedKeyUsage` to `req.conf` - getting the same error. Regarding adding the debug - I'm getting a lot of information, not sure where to start and look, the bottom line is `main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, bad_certificate`