# OpenSSL extensions to CA certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Im using OpenSSL v1.1.1g and trying to add extensions to my self signed CA certificate using the following bat script:

```
rem #Create CSR
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout ca-key.pem -out ca.csr -subj "..." -addext "keyUsage = cRLSign, digitalSignature, keyCertSign"
rem #Sign it
openssl x509 -signkey ca-key.pem -in ca.csr -req -days 365 -out ca-cert.pem -extfile extensions.cnf
pause
```

This is contents of extensions.cnf:

```
subjectAltName=DNS:localhost,IP:0.0.0.0,IP:127.0.0.1
crlDistributionPoints = URI:http://localhost:4444/crl.crl
keyUsage = cRLSign, digitalSignature, keyCertSign
basicConstraints=critical,CA:true,pathlen:0
```

It seems that neither -addext nor -extfile add keyusage to the cert, but crlDistributionPoints and basicConstraints work.
Can someone post a solution how to add keyusage contents through similar command line commands? I do not want to edit openssl.cnf.

EDIT: Added image of CA cert
[CAcert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opStj.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69088730/6368697 ; but otherwise your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thats the question i was looking initially and didnt get it to work. This may be offtopic but then so is the link you posted.

Comment: "and didnt get it to work. " yes, and more precisely? what is not working? "This may be offtopic but then so is the link you posted. " Correct, both questions are offtopic. Presence of one does not make the other suddenly on topic.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek "It seems that neither -addext nor -extfile add keyusage to the cert, but crlDistributionPoints and basicConstraints work" I need to add keyusage to the cert but the way i described doesnt seem to add it, but does add other fields. Im looking for suggestions on how to add keyusage to the cert without editing the base config (openss.cnf)

Comment: For me the above commands work perfectly so until you disclose EXACTLY what you typed and the results, as well as the versions used, I don't think anyone can help you. But don't do that here as it is not ontopic. [su] might be a relevant choice, do read their Help section.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Those were the exact commands and ive mentioned the version of OpenSSL that i used. I added image of the CA cert with missing fields. Did you get the same result? Could you post your result and commands since i think we have a slight difference in some part. I still dont think this is offtopic since scripting automated systems is coding.

Comment: " since scripting automated systems is coding.".  There is no "scripting" in your question, just 2 commands being run. This is a stretch to call this "scripting".

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Did you have any suggestions? Whats your output of something like `openssl x509 -noout -text -in cert.crt` or browser window? Lets not argue about pointless things.

Comment: Being on topic or not is absolutely not pointless. Quite the opposite. So I won't indulge in further debugging in comments, which is also wrong even if the question was ontopic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the reason for all this whackery was my aversion of openssl.cnf.
The default config was used in background and i just had to create a minimal one by myself rather than using the default.